# X a locally compact Haussdorf space, each singleton of which is the intersection of countably many open sets. Show that X is first countable.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact Haussdorf space, each singleton of which is the intersection of countably many open sets.

Show that X is first countable.

Comment: The earlier question isn’t quite a duplicate, but the same proof works: since your $X$ is locally compact, at each $a\in X$ you can work inside a compact nbhd of $a$ and carry out the same argument there.